# How to get a value by URL, preventing typos?

Tags: javascript, url

I'd like to get the ID (1337) out of every URL you can find below. What's the best way? The ID is always numeric. Maybe split by "/" and take the first numeric value? I appreciate your ideas.

Actually the URL is like the first one, but I'd like to prevent typos.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vKJfw/

```
/* outputs "1337" */
var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/module/action/1337/"; 

/* error: outputs "action" */
// var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/module/action/1337";

/* error: outputs "action" */
// var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/module/action/1337#"; 

/* error: outputs "" */
// var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/module/action/1337//";

/* error: outputs "bla" */
// var url = "http://www.mydomain.com/module/action/1337/bla/?x=y";

var url_parts = url.split("/");
var id        = url_parts[url_parts.length-2];

alert(id); // should output "1337" everytime!
```

Comment: Can't you just look for `/module/action/(\d+)*` (roughly)?

Comment: The start of the examples is always the same, so don't try to read it from a variable end. Just go from the front: `str.split('/')[5]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var id        = parseInt(url_parts[5]);
```

Works for all of your examples.

You could also use a regular expression to find the first number:

```
var reg = /\d+/;
var id = reg.exec(url);
```

Using a regular expression might be a more robust solution.

Comment: I didn't mention, the base-URL could change (e.g. localhost). RegEx could be a solution. I'll check it. Thanks!